# Preconditioner for diagonally dominant arrow matrix

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the block matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\
B^{\intercal} & C
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a matrix of fixed bandwidth while $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times c}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{c\times c}$ are dense matrices. Pictorially, the matrix has sparsity pattern
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}\star &  &  &  & \star\\
 & \star &  &  & \star\\
 &  & \ddots &  & \star\\
 &  &  & \star & \star\\
\star & \star & \star & \star & \star
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Moreover, $M$ is diagonally dominant. I am interested in solving systems of the form $Mx=b$ where the dimension $n$ may grow quickly but $c$ does not.

As such, I am looking for references on effective preconditioners for this and similar systems.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to solve this by an iterative method? First, the matrix is diagonally dominant, so an LU factorization can be performed without pivoting. Second, Since $A$ is banded, the other matrices are dense, and given the structure of $M$, the factors would have the same sparsity pattern as $M$. So the complexity of the factorization is proportional to the number of nonzeros in $M$ which is $O(n)$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: The reason is that it comes from a discretization of a PDE and the bandwidth grows as the discretization gets finer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reference may be a good jumping off point:

http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/mor.pdf

This is a fairly common type of linear system that arises in systems with constrains (like Navier-Stokes ...) and as such there are lots of ways to go about preconditioning. Typically, however, the best preconditions come from looking at the overall problem you want to solve. For instance, with Navier-Stokes, the discrete system would have $A$ representing a momentum operator of some kind, while $B \equiv Grad$, $B^{T} \equiv Div$. In this case, it's best to precondition this by using a projection method (if you're not familiar, this is just a different numerical method to solve N-S through operator splitting) as an approximate inverse. While this is very application specific, the point I'm making is that this is good! You can really make big dents in the number of Krylov solver iterations by just looking for 'approximate solution methods' to your original (possibly continuum?) problem, rather than looking at linear algebra tricks for the resulting linear system. I could try to say more if you want to say more about where the problem comes from, but the reference I gave should be a good start. Happy hunting!